# Caching issue for iPad/iPhone in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ipad, asp.net-mvc-4, caching, safari

I have a simple MVC project that displays some information for a logged in user. The controller and the action have the [Authorize] attribute and the controller also has the NoCacheAttribute as below:

```
public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{  
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

If I logout from the app and hit the back screen, on all desktop browser it redirects me to Login page, but on Safari on iPad2 I still have the cached info page and renders in a weird way the Login page on top of the info page (somehow in the center of the screen).

I am guessing this is a caching problem on iPad since I want the unauthenticated user not to be able to see the info page.

Does anyone encountered this issue?

Thanks,
Tamash

Comment: Have you cleared the browser history on the iPad since implementing the NoCacheAttribute?

Comment: Yes, i have cleared the browser history and still no luck.

Comment: @Tamas, did you get any solution for this? I am having the same problem with iPhone 4s after logout. Please post the solution if anyone has found the solution.

Comment: Nope. Eventually we made a forced redirect to another page and that sort of sorted out (hack solution though, would love to see another solution for this problem).

Comment: @TamasIonut, could you please help how you did that in MVC? how you implemented forced redirect for back button?